# Longest Incresing Subsequence using std::set in c++

Tags: c++, algorithm

I have found a code for LIS in a book, I am not quite able to work out the proof for correctness . Can some one help me out with that. All the code is doing is deleting the element next to new inserted element in the set if the new element is not the max else just inserting the new element.

```
    set<int> s;
    set<int>::iterator it;
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
         s.insert(arr[i]);
             it=s.find(arr[i]);
         it++; 
         if(it!=s.end()) 
           s.erase(it);
    }
    cout<<s.size()<<endl;
```

n is the size of sequence and arr is the sequence. I dont think the following code will work if we dont have to find "strictly" increasing sequences . Can we modify the code to find increasing sequences in which equality is allowed.

EDIT: the algorithm works only when the input are distinct.

Comment: What is the output of the algorithm?

Comment: A solution from _"The Hitchhiker’s Guide to the Programming Contests"_ for LIS

Comment: @P0W yes it is from that book but I didn't find it relevant to mention the exact name of the book so I didn't mention it.

Comment: Given the input 4, 5, 0, 1, 2, 3 it looks like the result will be 4, 5 which is wrong.

Comment: @Alan Stokes run the program. The output is 4 and the set is 0,1,2,3

Comment: `for(int i=0,i<n;i++)`: Shouldn't this be `for(int i=0;i<n;i++)` ?

Comment: I think it will fail for `1 2 3 4 1`

Comment: Yes it is a typo. I will edit the ques.

Comment: The algorithm outputs 3 for the input sequence 1 2 3 4 1, whereas it should be 4.

Comment: @user2179293 See [here](http://ideone.com/QXsXfq)

Comment: For the input 4, 5, 6, 0, 1 the count is correct but `s` does not contain the LIS - see [here](http://ideone.com/ufxapG).

Comment: Ok. The set does not contain the LIS and this algorithm works only if the inputs are distinct. I didn't know that. Thanks for correcting the question.

Comment: Possibly related?  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Patience_sorting

Comment: The edit from the OP is misleading. It says the algorithm only works if the input is distinct. That is not true, the algorithm **works even if there are duplicate elements in the input**. The algorithm doesn't work when we have to find longest non decreasing subsequence.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several solutions to LIS.
The most typical is O(N^2) algorithm using dynamic programming, where for every index i you calculate "longest increasing sequence ending at index i".
You can speed this up to O(N log N) using clever data structures or binary search.

Your code bypasses this and only calculated the length of the LIS.
Consider input "1 3 4 5 6 7 2", the contents of the set at the end will be "1 2 4 5 6 7", which is not the LIS, but the length is correct. 
Proof should go using induction as follows:

After i-th iteration the j-th smallest element is the smallest possible end of increasing sequence of the length j in the first i elements of the array.

Consider input "1 3 2". After second iteration we have set "1 3", so 1 is smallest possible end of increasing sequence of length 1 and 3 is smallest possible end of increasing sequence of length 2.
After third iteration we have set "1 2", where now the 2 is smallest possible end of increasing sequence of length 2.

I hope you can do induction step by yourself :)

Comment: If n=10 and elements are 5,3,4,9,6,2,1,8,7,10 then after fourth iteration the last element must be 5(a set of size 3 is formed and elements 5,3,4,9 have been scanned) but the last element is 9.

Comment: After 1 iteration you have: "5", after second: "3" (you delete 5), after third: "3 4", after fourth: "3 4 9".

Comment: Ok, I got it but can we modify the algo to support duplicate elements, as set does not inserts duplicates.

Comment: Use multiset and instead of find and ++it, use upper_bound to find greater element than x.

Answer (score 2):

The code is a O(nlogn) solution for LIS, but you want to find the non-strictly increasing sequence, the implementation has a problem because the std::set doesn't allow duplicate element. Here is the code that works.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <set>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int arr[] = {4, 4, 5, 7, 6};
    int n = 5;
    multiset<int> s;
    multiset<int>::iterator it;
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        s.insert(arr[i]);
        it = upper_bound(s.begin(), s.end(), arr[i]);
        if(it!=s.end()) 
            s.erase(it);
    }
    cout<<s.size()<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I know this solution. I liked the set solution because it was very short. So I was thinking of similar solutions . Anyways, thanks for the reply.

Comment: @user2179293 I got what you mean. Then we need a set which allows the duplicate elements and ordered. The std::multiset is perfect! I'll edit the answer.

Comment: This code will fail for `{0, 8, 4, 12, 2, 10, 6, 14, 1, 9, 5, 13, 3, 11, 7, 15}`, which gives wrong result `{(0, 1, 3, 7, 11, 15)}`.

Comment: @herohuyongtao for your test case, the length of LIS is exactly 6, I don't think it fails.

Comment: But the elements of LIS in `multiset<int> s` is not correct. Right?

Comment: @herohuyongtao It's also correct. It's just one of the LISs. {0,2,6,9,11,15} is the same.

Comment: When I tested your code, it returns `{(0, 1, 3, 7, 11, 15)}`, not `{0,2,6,9,11,15}`.

Comment: @herohuyongtao This means both of them are the Longest Incresing Subsequences.

Comment: No, there is no `{7, 11, 15}` sub-sequence in the input.

Comment: @herohuyongtao Oh, I got it. It seems this algorithm doesn't guarantee the LIS is in the set.

Comment: @herohuyongtao Actually, if you regard the set as a sorted array, s[k] contains the smallest element of sequence that ends an ascending subsequence of length k. It's a coincidence that elements of the set container are one of the LISs. If you want to find all LISs, read this paper: http://www.ii.uni.wroc.pl/~lorys/IPL/article76-1-1.pdf

Comment: In this implementation it = upper_bound(s.begin(), s.end(), arr[i]); this line have some issue. The time complexity of this line is O(n^2) as upper_bound() run on a random access iterator and multiset and set are not a random access data structure. So I think it should be it = s.upper_bound(arr[i]);

Answer (score 2):

The proof is relatively straightforward: consider set `s` as a sorted list. We can prove it with a [loop invariant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loop_invariant). After each iteration of the algorithm, `s[k]` contains the smallest element of `arr` that ends an ascending subsequence of length `k` in the sub-array from zero to the last element of `arr` that we have considered so far. We can prove this by induction:

- After the first iteration, this statement is true, because `s` will contain exactly one element, which is a trivial ascending sequence of one element.
- Each iteration can change the set in one of two ways: it could expand it by one in cases when `arr[i]` is the largest element found so far, or replace an existing element with `arr[i]`, which is smaller than the element that has been there before.

When an extension of the set occurs, it happens because the current element `arr[i]` can be appended to the current LIS. When a replacement happens at position `k`, the index of `arr[i]`, it happens because `arr[i]` ends an ascending subsequence of length `k`, and is smaller than or is equal to the old `s[i]` that used to end the previous "best" ascending subsequence of length `k`.

With this invariant in hand, it's easy to see that `s` contains as many elements as the longest ascending subsequence of `arr` after the entire `arr` has been exhausted.

Answer (score -2):

Problem Statement:

```
  For A(n) :a0, a1,….an-1 we need to find LIS

  Find all elements in A(n) such that, ai<aj and i<j.
  For example: 10, 11, 12, 9, 8, 7, 5, 6
  LIS will be 10,11,12
```

This is O(N^2) solution based on DP.

```
1 Finding SubProblems
Consider D(i): LIS of (a0 to ai) that includes ai as a part of LIS.
2 Recurrence Relation
D(i) = 1 + max(D(j) for all j<i) if ai > aj
3 Base Case
D(0) = 1;
```

Check out link for the code:
https://innosamcodes.wordpress.com/2013/07/06/longest-increasing-subsequence/

Comment: I know the conventional O(n^2) and O(nlogn) approaches but my question was specific for this approach.

Comment: And how does this answer the question ?